RC filter to DC 12V, 3A fan PWM
This feels like a question asked hundreds of times before, yet doesn't seem to have a good solution.  If a company could sell me a solution, I would buy it in a heartbeat.
I have a van with a 3A 12VDC fan driven and controlled by a Spyder G6 van touchscreen system.  The fan produces an intense 10 kHz whine at all speed settings except max. I believe this to indicate that it is controlled by a 10 kHz PWM and varying duty cycles (likely 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%). Modifying the the PWM on the Spyder board looks near impossible, and the firmware is not accessible.  Replacing the Spyder system (or the van) is going to be stupidly expensive. I do have access to the two wires leading to fan, a Dometic FV8300LWUSF81C.  The fact of two wires, and the low replacement cost, suggests that it is a brushed motor.  I have driven the fan with a benchtop variable power supply, and it does not produce the 10 kHz noise.
A gifted engineer suggested I divide the 12VDC PWM, measure it with an Arduino, re-output it at a higher PWM like 50 kHz, then drive a motor controller with that.  I keep hoping for a simpler solution that produces an analog(ish) DC voltage.
I am considering trying an RC filter, say with a 20 kOhm resistor and a 100 nF capacitor, however, I am unclear on how to calculate how this would effect the ultimate top end voltage applied to the fan, and whether it would lead to a change in the low end voltage for small duty cycles.  Nor have I been able to assess power dissipation across the components, and whether they would immediately burst into flames.
Some on this forum have mentioned "buck regulators", but extensive searches on google have not found a device that appears to output a range of DC voltages given a PWM input.
Can anyone help?
Thanks!

The fan draws 3 A at 12 V, that’s the equivalent of 4 Ohms. If you put a 20 kOhm resistor in series, using the voltage divider formula you will get:
$$
V_{R_X} = V_{In}\cdot\frac{R_{X}}{R_{Total}} = 12 V \cdot \frac{4\Omega}{20004\Omega} = 2.4mV
$$
across the fan. That’s probably not going to work very well. This is why an RC filter won’t work, a resistance large enough to provide effective filtering will severely limit the current. What you might try instead is an LC filter. An inductor can have a high impedance to 10 kHz AC while still having a very low DC resistance.
One possible solution is a commercial alternator whine filter, these are a high current inductor and a capacitor meant to filter alternator noise for things like car audio systems.
Update:
I've done a quick simulation with an inductor and capacitor with a 4\$\Omega\$ resistor as the fan. 10 kHz @ 12 V square wave input with 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 100% duty cycles.

The inductance and capacitance could be changed, if you increase one you decrease the other by the same scale, so say you use a 10 mH inductor, change the cap to something like 22uF. Values aren't too critical, more inductance or capacitance filters better but getting up to a steady voltage would be slower (here it's about 5 ms).

Thanks!  That is the most actionable suggestion I have received!  I have found a few of these devices available.  Maybe something like this:  [link] (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0C2JY4YQN/ref=sspa_dk_detail_4?psc=1&pd_rd_i=B0C2JY4YQN&pd_rd_w=Z72je&content-id=amzn1.sym.eb7c1ac5-7c51-4df5-ba34-ca810f1f119a&pf_rd_p=eb7c1ac5-7c51-4df5-ba34-ca810f1f119a&pf_rd_r=PGTVCRH9QBTRV0ZGVCQK&pd_rd_wg=v33aQ&pd_rd_r=9c5762cc-a1ba-4ae5-b685-17d02a7f8fcb&s=car&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWw)

@Riprock99 Hard to say for sure without knowing what's inside the filter, but that's the general type of thing. There are less expensive ones that are basically a toroidal inductor and an electrolytic cap in some heat shrink with wires sticking out. I've added a simulation screenshot to my answer, have a look at that as well.

Hi GodJihyo, thanks for the analysis!  I went parts shopping, and I noticed that inductors have more specifications than I anticipated - like saturation and current specifications.  Is there one you might recommend?

Hi GodJihyo, I tried an alternator EMI filter today on the fan.  It knocked down the noise significantly.  Thanks for the suggestion and the help!
